# Unable to use Eth0 to ping Google. Works with Wlan0

Tags: networking, ethernet

I played with my Network configuration, and it seems like I am unable to connect to Internet using eth0 anymore. I am able to with wlan0. Here are the things I compared with the supposed configuration (in this demo wlan0 is disabled), if you notice a problem, advise me :

**~ $ wget google.com**

--2019-08-12 15:32:22--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘google.com’

**~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf**

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 10.1.1.1

nameserver 8.8.4.4

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces**
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

**$ ping -c 1 8.8.8.8**

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.$$.$$$ icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping -c 1 google.com**

ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route**

default dev eth0 scope link src 169.254.$$.$$$ metric 202
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link src 169.254.$$.$$$ metric 202

**pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip addr**

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group

default qlen 1000

link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 ::1/128 scope host

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP

group default qlen 1000

link/ether b8:27:eb:4e:50:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 169.254.$$.$$$/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 fe80::c40a:a8db:ca0b:5095/64 scope link

valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default

qlen 1000

link/ether b8:27:eb:1b:05:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

**dhcpd.conf**

persistent

option rapid_commit

option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name

option classless_static_routes

option ntp_servers

option interface_mtu

require dhcp_server_identifier

slaac private

**If you need more info, just tell me !**

Comment: You don't have any proper IP address on eth0. This could be due to anything, e.g. plugged into a switch that's not connected to your router.

Comment: 169.254.**.**, it's my eth0 ip ;)

Comment: No, that's an automatically assigned link-local address that your system gave itself, becuase it couldn't get a real IP address.

Comment: Oh, interesting ! But I am able to SSH connect to this machine using this IP

Comment: Only from within your network ("link-*local*"). This Ip can't be routed. So find out why your eth0 is not getting a correct IP address.